# Could not run java bytecode on windows, compiled on mac

Tags: java

I have written a simple java program on mac and compiled using javac option. To demonstrate it's platform independent, I copied the .class file to a windows machine (via email) and run java . However, it's giving error saying `could not find or load main class...`

I compared the java version on both mac and windows; both are same, except build version.

Below is the **mac java version**:

```
:~/Desktop/compare/javatest$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_211"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)
```

Here is the simple java program:

```
public class Main {


    private int number1 = 0;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }

    void doSomething() {
        int number4=0;

        number4=number1+number1;

        int number2 =0;
    }
    int number3=0;
}
```

Attaching the error from windows machine[image]

Comment: Is `Main.class` in `C:\Users\Admin\Downloads`?

Comment: Yes; it's under that folder

Comment: Try `java -cp . Main`

Comment: Maybe the current directory is not in the class path. Try adding it explicitly via tha `-cp .` flag.

Comment: Yes! adding the `-cp .` solved the issue. Thanks a lot!
C:\Users\Admin\Downloads>java -cp . Main
Hello World!

Comment: ' java -classpath <path to the class> <classname>' worked for me. See if this helps.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean

Answer (score 0):

i also face this problem , then solve my problem by using this code

```
javac Test.java
java -cp . Test
```